# ComponentModel, PropertyGrids and Interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, propertygrid, system.componentmodel

I have a bunch of objects that implement different interfaces, some properties of this interfaces should be showed and edited through a PropertyGrid, but if I specify something like DisplayName, Browsable or DescriptionAttribute, they will not be "inherited" by the class that implements the interface... why is this? and is there any solution?

Comment: You will see some explanations in 2 existing posts. [What’s the use of attributes on an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590336/whats-the-use-of-attributes-on-an-interface)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use of attributes on an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590336/whats-the-use-of-attributes-on-an-interface)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Unfortunately, attributes implement themselves on a specific type.  The interface is a separate type than the member that implements the interface.

You'll need to specify those attributes on each class.  It's more work, but it also is more flexible (since those classes can determine exactly how to show their information, and customize as needed).