# How to stop ASP.NET web API from implicitly interpretering the HTTP method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It seems ASP.NET implicitly interprets method named `GetX` and `PostX` as GET and POST methods respectively, because of their names are prefixed with HTTP method names. This is also the case for PUT and DELETE.

I have a method unfortunately named `Delete` but I want it to be interpreted as a POST, so I explicitly specify it's a POST using the `[HttpPost]` attribute. This works, as long as it's not declared inside an interface...

```
public interface IFooBarController
{
    [HttpPost]
    void DoSomething();

    [HttpPost]
    void Delete(int id);
}

public class FooBarController : IFooBarController
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
       // This API method can only be called using POST,
       // as you would expect from the interface.
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        // This API method can only be called using DELETE,
        // even though the interface specifies [HttpPost].
    }
}
```

How can I work around this, without having to specify the HttpPostAttribute for each implementation?

Comment: Will you be using Attribute routing with this web api?

Comment: It seems to me that http verbs are implementation details and don't belong in an interface.

Comment: @BigDaddy, I would argue they are a part of the API method signature.

Comment: @Nkosi, no, we currently have our routing configured to include the full C# method name in the route.

Comment: I thought you might say that ;)  The class is required to provide the implementation of interface methods.  Why not convert the interface to an abstract class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, attributes are not inherited. DoSomething is not called using POST because of the attribute in your interface but because that is the default. Change it to GET in your interface and you will still notice POST calling it.

You can read more on how action selection is performed [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) in the section "Action Selection". (Item 3 answers your question regarding why DoSomething is called using POST)

Answer (score 4):

Attributes on interface properties doesn't get inherited to the class, you may make your interface to an Abstract Class.

Found an answer from [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1748587a-f13c-4dd7-9fec-c8d57014632c/code-first-dataannotations-in-interfaces?forum=adonetefx):

> The product team does not want to implement this feature, for two main
>   reasons:
>
> - Consistency with DataAnnotations.Validator
> - Consistency with validation behavior in ASP.Net MVC
> - tricky scenario: a class implements two
>     interfaces that have the same property, but with conflicting
>     attributes on them. Which attribute would take precedence?

SOURCES: [Attribute on Interface members does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106566/attribute-on-interface-members-does-not-work)

Comment: I asked this on another question but I'll repeat it here. If attributes aren't inherited, how come an interface method `[HttpPost] DoSomething()` can only be called using POST, even though the implementation of said interface does not repeat the HttpPostAttribute?

Comment: you have to bypass an abstract class.

Comment: wait i can t verify now ;) i ll do it when i m back to home :p

Answer (score 1):

Attributes aren't inherited from implemented interfaces, you'll have to declare the attribute on the concrete implementation (FooBarController). This overrides the convention-based binding.

Comment: If that's true, how come an interface method `[HttpPost] DoSomething()` can only be called using POST, even though the implementation of said interface does not repeat the HttpPostAttribute?

Answer (score -2):

use [ActionName] attribue and name it as you want