# Custom Attributes with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, interface, nsubstitute

I'm currently mocking out an `Interface` with `NSubstitute`, which is basically a representation of a class with two properties and one method.

```
LoginViewModel = Substitute.For<ILoginViewModel>();
```

The mocked out interface is instantiated, then passed into a method which reflects upon it to get all the custom attributes.

```
LoginViewModel.Username = "User1";
LoginViewModel.Password = "Password1";
```

Each of the properties on the concrete implementation of the interface has a single custom attribute, however when reflected, the compiler shows no custom attributes.

```
[CustomRequired]
public string Username { get; set; }

[CustomRequired]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Testing this *without* NSubstitute works. My question is: Does NSubstitute strip out Custom Attributes? Or is there a way to allow them through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know too much about custom attributes, so it is worth [double checking the information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx) in my answer.

First, NSubstitute does strip out [some specific attributes](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/e90132f914a644ba1f50fb8edf8b0dd792c64acb/Source/NSubstitute/Proxies/CastleDynamicProxy/CastleDynamicProxyFactory.cs#L92), but not attributes in general. (Aside: NSubstitute uses Castle DynamicProxy to generate the proxy types, so to be more accurate NSubstitute asks Castle DP to strip these out. :) )

Secondly, if the attributes are declared on an interface they will [not flow on to the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12106626/906). They will however be available via the interface type itself. They will also be available if declared on a class and on substitutes for that class (provided the attribute is not configured explicitly to [prevent being inherited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute { }
public interface IHaveAttributes {
    [My] string Sample { get; set; }
}
public class HaveAttributes : IHaveAttributes {
    [My] public virtual string Sample { get; set; }
}
public class NoAttributes : IHaveAttributes {
    public virtual string Sample { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void TestAttributes()
{
    // WORKS for class:
    var sub = Substitute.For<HaveAttributes>();
    var sampleProp = sub.GetType().GetProperty("Sample");
    var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(sampleProp, typeof(MyAttribute));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, attributes.Length);

    // WORKS directly from interface:
    var sampleInterfaceProp = typeof(IHaveAttributes).GetProperty("Sample");
    var attributes2 = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(sampleInterfaceProp, typeof(MyAttribute));
    Assert.AreEqual(1, attributes2.Length);

    // Does NOT go from interface through to class (even non-substitutes):
    var no = new NoAttributes();
    var sampleProp2 = no.GetType().GetProperty("Sample");
    var noAttributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(sampleProp2, typeof(MyAttribute));
    Assert.IsEmpty(noAttributes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I've added the custom attributes on both the Interface and the Class, however there are still no attributes. Here is a screenshot of the reflected type: http://i.imgur.com/xjPKLqF.png

Comment: The screenshot shows it is still looking at declaring type `ILoginViewModelProxy`. You'll have substitute for the class (`LoginViewModel`?) if you want the members to have those attributes.

Comment: Ahh makes sense! Thanks so much - Working now :)