# In C#, do attributes defined in an interface apply to implementing classes?

Tags: c#, interface, attributes

I've read from plenty of places that attributes defined in interface **DO NOT** apply to implementing classes, and simply get ignored:

- [Can a C# class inherit attributes from its interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540749/can-a-c-sharp-class-inherit-attributes-from-its-interface)
- [Attribute on Interface members does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106566/attribute-on-interface-members-does-not-work)
- http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/08/interface-attributes-class-attributes.html

However, it seems like that attributes **DO** apply to implementing classes:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

interface TestInterface
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "foo")]
    string id { get; set; }
}

class Test : TestInterface
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Test()));
    }
}

Console Output: {"foo": null}
```

In the above example, JsonProperty attribute is clearly being applied in the implementing class (changing "id" field name to "foo" for serialization).

Did the behavior of C# attributes in interface change or am I missing something?

Comment: Attributes are queried using reflection. It's up to the code which does the query whether to check the inheritance tree or not. So, the question is, "ignored by *what*"? (and I guess JSON.net checks the tree - other libraries may not)

Comment: If you look at the link "Attribute on Interface members does not work", the author has a code where attributes do not apply from interfaces, but works from abstract classes. So, it seems like attributes were NOT available via reflection on interface-implementing classes before... (but now it is working via my example)

Comment: In that case, perhaps JSON.Net actually enumerates the implemented interfaces and checks for attributes manually.. Can you try querying the attribute yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attributes are queried via reflection and can be accessed in whatever way the developer wants to. To show proof of how this works in your example code, I had a look at the [NewtonSoft.Json source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) to see how it loaded this value.

The way it gets the `JsonProperty` attribute is by calling the following on a `MemberInfo`.

```
JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>(member)
```

The source for this method at the time of this question can be seen [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/ab3315f1d5e57c70203c904be79d8e951bf09794/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L335)

As you can see on lines [364-376](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/ab3315f1d5e57c70203c904be79d8e951bf09794/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L364-L376), it loops over the `MemberInfo`'s interfaces, then tries to get the attribute from the interface if it is unable to load the JsonProperty from the class it is being used on.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer and the reference to the code. How good of them to actually take a look at the interface to pull out JsonProperty attributes when they are missing :)