# CustomAttribute not being correctly filtered when registering components by convention

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, attributes, castle-windsor, conventions

I have the below custom attribute; it is to label interfaces that need explicit registration rather than depending on registration by convention in Castle Windsor:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(
        AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class, 
        Inherited = true)]
public class ExplicitDependencyRegistrationRequiredAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

This is then applied to the interface like so:

```
using Dependencies.Attributes;

[ExplicitDependencyRegistrationRequired]
public interface IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    int GetRandomNumber(int max);
}
```

Which has a simple concrete implementation below:

```
using System;

public class RandomNumberGenerator : IRandomNumberGenerator
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    public int GetRandomNumber(int max)
    {
        return random.Next(max);
    }
}
```

The idea is that when registering components by convention in Castle Windsor we don't have to worry about duplicating registrations or adding exceptions; instead we just need to ensure the interface is marked with this attribute.  Then the code to filter it is below:

```
Type exclusionType = typeof(ExplicitDependencyRegistrationRequiredAttribute);

BasedOnDescriptor selectedTypes =
    Classes
      .FromAssembly(assembly)
      .Where(t => !Attribute.IsDefined(t, exclusionType, true))
      .WithServiceAllInterfaces();
```

The problem is that the `Attribute.IsDefined` filter does not seem to be working, the components inheriting from an interface with the attribute present are still being registered.

When I explicitly add the attribute to the `RandomNumberGenerator` class the filter works; however it does not appear to be inheriting from the interface *or* Castle Windsor is not correctly picking up the custom attribute.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes on interfaces [are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540749/can-a-c-sharp-class-inherit-attributes-from-its-interface) by the class implementing the interface.  You need to declare the attribute (again) on the class for it to work the way you want.