# Check if Generic Interface Member is "Pure" (has Pure Attribute)

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface, custom-attributes

I have an interface with methods annotated with the `Pure` attribute from `System.Diagnostics.Contracts`:

```
public interface IFoo<T> {
    [Pure]
    T First { get; }

    [Pure]
    T Last { get; }

    [Pure]
    T Choose();

    void Add(T item);

    T Remove();
}
```

I wish to iterate over the members of the interface and check if the member is pure or not.
Currently I'm not able to get any attributes from the member info:

```
var type = typeof(IFoo<>);
var memberInfos = type.GetMembers();
var memberInfo = memberInfos.First(); // <-- Just select one of them
var attributes = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributesData(); // <-- Empty
```

What am I missing?

Note that I do not have a class or an instance hereof. Only the interface.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540749/can-a-c-sharp-class-inherit-attributes-from-its-interface

You may want to reconsider having the attributes on your interface.

Comment: But isn't that question about classes inheriting the attributes? I **only** want to look at the interface and its **members**.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 And I don't really have any implementations to look at, only the interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a decompiler of your choice and open your assembly. You will see that the `PureAttribute` will be removed by the compiler. So you can not get it with reflection because is does not exist anymore.

To test you can use another attribute that wont get removed and you will be able to get it using reflection.

**Update**:
On the one hand, as you have mentioned in the comments:

> Pure is a conditional attribute ([Conditional("CONTRACTS_FULL")]), and is only added if contracts are enable.

On the other hand your code has a flaw because Linqs `First()` method will return a member without an attribute, the getter method of the property. You can use code like this to get the expected result: `members.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<PureAttribute>().Any()).ToArray()`.

Comment: Okay, I see. It is in fact gone. Then tell me: how does Code Contracts know if a method is pure or not?

Comment: To be honest, i don't know, maybe there is another or slightly modified compiler in use.

Comment: Oh, wait. Pure is a conditional attribute (`[Conditional("CONTRACTS_FULL")]`), and is only added if contracts are enable. The attribute is actually visible in the assembly (using dotPeeks) if CC are enabled - however, they still do not show up with reflection.

Comment: For me it works `members.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<PureAttribute>().Any()).ToArray()`. Maybe the member you are getting with linqs `First` returns a member without attribute like a getter method.

Comment: You're right, that's exactly the problem with using the LINQ `First()` method. The first member is the `get` method for `First`, not the property itself, and the `get` method in fact has no attributes on it.

Comment: But of course, what a stupid mistake! Perfect it seems to work now. @thehennyy Do you wanna update your answer to reflect this?